# Anyway to watch for system wide multitouch events on osx?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have seen that it is possible to use `addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:` to watch for system wide events for mouse events, scroll events, key events, and even gesture events. I looked at NSEvents.h for the available event masks, but just could not find one for multi-touch events. Is it possible to do this for multi-touch events?

Comment: Wondering if this would useful to you:  http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?MultiTouch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I looked at NSEvents.h for the available event masks, but just could not find one for multi-touch events.

Looks like developer.apple.com has some documentation on the NSEvent class and refer to some touch events/gestures.

"Support for touch and gesture events masks have been added to NSEvent in Mac OS X v10.6...."
[developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

If you're developing for an older OS version than the one specified in the quote, let me know.

EDIT:
As far as the function you referenced it looks like the documentation says that touch events are currently not supported.

"In Mac OS X v 10.6, event monitors are only able to monitor the following event types..."
[addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Doing a find using the link provided will take you to the list of supported events. However, in the case that the link no longer works:

In Mac OS X v 10.6, event monitors are only able to monitor the following event types:

NSLeftMouseDragged,
NSRightMouseDragged,
NSOtherMouseDragged,
NSLeftMouseUp,
NSRightMouseUp,
NSOtherMouseUp,
NSLeftMouseDown,
NSRightMouseDown,
NSOtherMouseDown,
NSMouseMoved,
NSFlagsChanged,
NSScrollWheel,
NSTabletPoint,
NSTabletProximity,
NSKeyDown (Key repeats are determined by sending the event an isARepeat message.)

Comment: Thank you for the research. I had came to the same conclusion but it's nice to get confirmation from someone else.